# Robot.createScreenCapture() does not always produce pixels

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I have the code:

```
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
System.out.println(pixels[0*4]);
```

where "robot" is an instance of the class "Robot" created elsewhere.

Sometimes, this code outputs "-1", meaning that the first pixel is, somehow, invalid. Other times, this code outputs a number like "-1828129198" which is expected behavior.

Here is where things get weird. I have this piece of code, later in the same class:

```
private static void DebugImage(BufferedImage bi)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(bi)));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

When I first tested the first piece of code today, I got -1 as output. However, when I changed the original piece of code to include a call to DebugImage, as follows:

```
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(area);
DebugImage(bi);
int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) bi.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
System.out.println(pixels[0*4]);
```

I suddenly stopped getting "-1", and finally got some valid data! The kicker? When I removed the call to DebugImage, putting it back into its original form, the code did not stop working, and continued to successfully *not* return -1. (NOTE: I am using Eclipse)

I imagine this must be thread related, or is perhaps some kind of memory management issue, but to be honest, I have very little indication as to what is going on.

Does anyone have any experience with using Robot for screenshot capture, or any ideas on how to prevent this?

Comment: Why is `-1` invalide?  Stupid I know ;)

Comment: -1 means all bits set to zero, which should never (or at least, rarely) happen. I don't think I have more than 120 fully black pixels on my screen, and to make matters worse, I get -1 for at least 100 indices after the first, not just the first one. Finally, when displaying the image, the first pixel is not black, which further confirms to me that -1 is invalid.

Comment: How often do you call this method?

Comment: The above code is executed only once. Notably, it crashes soon after this code is executed. You see, even when I got the -1's to not show up, they end up showing up later down the line when I convert the int[] pixels array to a byte[] array. They end up completely corrupting the data, which crashes my code later down the line. Honestly, I don't know how in the name of goodness the data is able to get messed up so utterly easily.

Comment: What OS?  It's "possible" that the `BufferedImage` is still being written to, that might explain why you can get `-1`, but still paint the image...

Comment: Mac OSX -- that sounds like a brilliant explanation, actually. Is there any way for me to wait for the image to actually finish being written?

Comment: You could try using a `ImageConsumer`

Comment: I did a quick test and I get `-1`, but have no issue painting the image.  The content of the pixel buffer doesn't change between updates (delayed for 1 second between updates).  I think the assumption that `-1` is a invalid pixel is erroneous.  If the image was to be invalid, it would be the wrong size or `null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `-1` means that all bits are set to 1. So, you will have plain white instead of black. That seems valid, to me. Since you told you were using Mac OS X, this could be right, because, look at the top left corner, it looks like this:

[image]
[image]

There might be some plain white there in the corner. The second picture contains perfectly plain white. This can be achieved by setting a white background (at least, white in the corner) and translucent top menu bar enabled.

Comment: Please try to write the BufferedImages to a file using `ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("debug.png"));` and see if they are actually invalid. Maybe that throws some light on the problem.

Comment: I cannot seem to get damning data on the matter, so I'll go ahead and accept your answer! It seems perhaps my issues were elsewhere.